# troubles with understanding how ASCII works

Tags: encoding, byte, ascii, bit

I have few questions about ASCII encoding:

1. How come there is 127 characters definable in ASCII coding? It should be 7-bit, which means 2 to the power of 7 which equals 128. Where is the one character missing?
2. When I save a textfile as a textfile.txt it should be saved in ASCII coding right? But when I write like 10 characters into the file it has 10 bytes, which is 80 bits, shouldnt it be 70 ?
3. How do I save a file to a kind of ASCII code which has 7 bits per character?
4. Do some softwares still use the ASCII encoding for storing the information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Ascii has 128 value, but they are enumerated from 0-127 like most computer arrays. 0 means null.
2) Either the ascii is fit into 8 bit, or you are using the extended 8 bit version.
3) Define your own program that writes to a bytestream, then you can check the bytes yourself.
4) Most readable text are encoded using UTF, but things that only need the basic characters, such as computer code, can still use ascii.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) How come there is 127 characters definable in ASCII coding ? It
>   should be 7-bit, which means 2 to the power of 7 which equals
>   128...where is the one character missing

The NUL character, whose ASCII code is 0. That's the one you missed.

> 2) When I save a textfile as a textfile.txt it should be saved in
>   ASCII coding right ? But when I write like 10 characters into the file
>   it has 10 bytes, which is 80 bits, shouldnt it be 70 ?

Storage systems (and main memory) tend to use a byte as the mininum piece of information to store, so a file full of standard ASCII characters waste one bit per character. Non english users give thanks for that, because it allowed to extend ASCII to 8 bits, giving codes to store accentuated vocals and things like that.

> 3) How do I save a file to a kind of ASCII code which has 7 bits per
>   character ?

Just make sure all your file contents are ASCII standard. You will not, however, recover those missing bits. A compression algorithm might take advantage of that to squeeze a text file a little, though.

> 4) Do some softweres still use the ASCII encoding for storing the
>   information ?

The vast majority of software use ASCII even to encode things that are not ASCII by themselves. Notable examples: e-mail, and the HTML source of this very page you are reading.

Answer (score 0):

Stepping back a bit…

ASCII is an archaic, nearly obsolete character set. That said, nearly all character sets in use are a superset of ASCII and have compatible encodings. For example, Unicode has the UTF-8 encoding which maps the bytes for the first 128 characters the same as ASCII. Windows-1252 has 251 characters with the first 128 the same as ASCII.

Many modern programming environments use Unicode (at least for their source code and/or strings): Java, .NET, XML, HTML, ….

So, if you are reading a file, don't assume that it is ASCII. And, if you are writing a file, you could loose data if your programming environment uses Unicode and you force the output to be ASCII. In either case, the intended character set and encoding should be known by readers and writers.